# The NPC follows the part but when i go near the NPC they leave the part and start going to random directions

Tags: roblox

So i'm trying to make an npc move to a part when i click on the npc, when i clicked on it all seemed well until i went near the npc, at that point it left the part and started moving to random directions. Is there something wrong?

Script:

```
    local value = script.Parent.FollowSurvivor
local value2 = workspace.Values.MoveToValue

function findNearestTorso(pos)
    local list = game.Workspace:children()
    local torso = nil
    local dist = 1000
    local temp = nil
    local human = nil
    local temp2 = nil
    for x = 1, #list do
        temp2 = list[x]
        if (temp2.className == "Model") and (temp2 ~= script.Parent) then
            temp = temp2:findFirstChild("Torso")
            human = temp2:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
            if (temp ~= nil) and (human ~= nil) and (human.Health > 0) then
                if (temp.Position - pos).magnitude < dist then
                    torso = temp
                    dist = (temp.Position - pos).magnitude
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return torso
end

while true do
    wait(0.5)
    local target = findNearestTorso(script.Parent.Torso.Position)
    if target ~= nil then
        if value.Value == true then
            script.Parent.Zombie:MoveTo(target.Position, target)
        end
        if value.Value == false then
            script.Parent.Zombie:MoveTo(workspace.MoveToPart.Position)
        end
    end
    end
```

Comment: Are your zombies walking into each other when you get close?

Comment: no they go into random directions when i get close to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script gets the nearest humanoid and goes towards it. When you walked next to it, it found your humanoid and it started following you.

Comment: thanks but i stopped working on it, but still thanks!